# How to listen to when it is tapped outside a dialog in flutter?

Tags: flutter

Just as the title says. I already set `barrierDismissible` to false when calling showDialog so that the Dialog is not dismissed when tapping outside of it. I tried wrapping the Dialog in a GestureDetector and listening to onTap but this only listens to when the dialog is tapped and not outside of it.

Comment: it's working on my end with barrierDismissible

Comment: you can try https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/ModalBarrier-class.html

Comment: @Doc Interesting. Is there a way to listen to taps on the ModalBarrier of a dialog?

Answer (score 1):

You can use await-then

```
 await showDialog(
       //Your Dialog Code
).then((val){
//here to run on dismiss codes 
    Navigator.pop(_context);
});
```

Comment: I want to listen to this from within my Dialog widget. Besides this is called when the dialog is already gone.

Comment: i think you should not use alertdialog for that try creating a custom widget using visibility and gesture detectors